# Certificate not found on Azure Web App (Loaded on some instance but not others)

Tags: azure, certificate, azure-web-app-service, x509certificate

On Azure Web Sites, we have certificates installed. Not sure why, but sometimes (after scaling up or down, after a deployment or after a website restart), it looks like the certificates cannot be found. We do have the app settings  WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES set to '*'.

In fact, we created a small web app which list on a web page the certificate founds and the instance id. We scaled the web site to 2 instances. What we found is that the web page lists the correct certificates on one instance, but not on the other.

The problem does not seem to correct itself either unless you restart and scale up and down the web site.

Answer (score 1):

> list on a web page the certificate founds and the instance id.

Which location did you use to get the certificate?

If I use C# and get cert from LocalMachine location, I can reproduce your issue. I see different certs from different instances. CN=AmorP2SRootCert is the cert which I uploaded to my web app before running the code.

```
X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
```

[image]
If I get cert from CurrentUser location instead of LocalMachine location. I can get the right cert from all the instances.

```
X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation. CurrentUser);
```

Comment: We had suspected this issue and did change the code to check in Current User store but we were still getting the behavior. We were starting to suspect that the VMs running in our app service plan were buggy. So, we simple clicked on a new service plan in the azure portal and the problem went away.... for how long, we don't know... Thanks for your help. I will up your answer, but I cannot mark it as an answer still